# Transposing a subset of columns in a Pandas DataFrame while using others as grouping variable?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, optimization, dataframe

Let's say I have a Pandas dataframe (that is already in the dataframe format):

```
x = [[1,2,8,7,9],[1,3,5.6,4.5,4],[2,3,4.5,5,5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['id1','id2','val1','val2','val3'])

id1 id2 val1 val2 val3
1   2   8.0  7.0  9
1   3   5.6  4.5  4
2   3   4.5  5.0  5
```

I want `val1`, `val2`, and `val2` in one column, with `id1` and `id2` as grouping variables. I can use this **extremely** convoluted code:

```
dfT = df.iloc[:,2::].T.reset_index(drop=True)
n_points = dfT.shape[0]
final = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    data = np.asarray([[df.ix[i,'id1']]*n_points, 
                      [df.ix[i,'id2']]*n_points,
                      dfT.ix[:,i].values]).T
    temp = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id1','id2','val'])
    final = pd.concat([final, temp], axis=0)
```

to get my dataframe into the correct format:

```
    id1 id2 val
0   1.0 2.0 8.0
1   1.0 2.0 7.0
2   1.0 2.0 9.0
0   1.0 3.0 5.6
1   1.0 3.0 4.5
2   1.0 3.0 4.0
0   2.0 3.0 4.5
1   2.0 3.0 5.0
2   2.0 3.0 5.0
```

but there must be a more efficient way of doing this, since on a large dataframe this takes way too long.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `variable`:

```
print (pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id1','id2'], value_name='val')
         .drop('variable', axis=1))

   id1  id2  val
0    1    2  8.0
1    1    3  5.6
2    2    3  4.5
3    1    2  7.0
4    1    3  4.5
5    2    3  5.0
6    1    2  9.0
7    1    3  4.0
8    2    3  5.0
```

Another solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (df.set_index(['id1','id2'])
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='val'))

   id1  id2  val
0    1    2  8.0
1    1    2  7.0
2    1    2  9.0
3    1    3  5.6
4    1    3  4.5
5    1    3  4.0
6    2    3  4.5
7    2    3  5.0
8    2    3  5.0
```

Comment: Wow, one line vs seven I had - beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

There's even a simpler one which can be done using [`lreshape`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L804)(Not yet documented though):

```
pd.lreshape(df, {'val': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']}).sort_values(['id1', 'id2'])
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I like this function too, but still is undocumented in official documentation :(

Comment: I know. Got to know about this function in one of ayhan's answer.

Comment: Oh. Maybe I missed those answers as I wasn't active during those times. Just started out recently. But I'm sure ayhan has used it. Maybe the tag doesn't say so.

Comment: I was surprised too, maybe search engine omit some answers.

Comment: for those using `ipython`: `pd.lreshape??` or `help(pd.lreshape)` will show nice docstring, including a small example ;)

Comment: This is cool too. Why did they implement lreshape when there is already melt (answer above)?

Comment: I presume `melt` groups all the categories of variables under one single column whereas `lreshape` allows us to choose multiple aggregations according to a repeated set of columns. You could still somehow manipulate `melt` into behaving like a `lreshape`. Maybe for a better readability?